# Are self-adjoint / Hermitian operators necessarily orthogonal / unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

I feel like self-adjoint / Hermitian operators are the "best" operators, since an operator that is self-adjoint can be orthogonally diagonalized, according to the Spectral Theorem (over the complex number field, an operator only needs to be normal to be orthogonally diagonalizable).

I know that self-adjoint implies normal, but does self-adjoint also imply orthogonal / unitary:  $AA^T = A^TA = I$?

Thanks,

Comment: No.  Consider $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.  This matrix is self-adjoint but not orthogonal.  It is also untrue that Hermitian matrices or necessarily unitary.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, @Bye_World :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not. A self-adjoint operator just need $A^T=A$.
Note the matrix of $T^*$ is the transposed of the matrix of $T$.

Comment: Got it - thanks@user193702.